# MVC ClientSideValidation using Inline Style?

Tags: css, model-view-controller, validation

Got a simple form, and I am using the data annotations and model to give automatic clientside validation. However it looks fairly rubbish, and although I can apply some CSS to the elements im finding it quite difficult to get them to display as tooltip style errors.

Ideally im after something like: http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demoValidators.html

However it seems like all these sort of implementations require new DOM elements to be added during the validation and then displayed, however by default we only have the single element that contains the validation message.

I was mainly wondering if there was any pre-made Jquery plugin or MVC compatible project that would allow me to do this style of validation with little effort, as im a coder not a designer.

If there is no simple way to do this then no worries, and thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have validation similar to the demo URL that uses MVC validation  and css - it's not too difficult to do - my CSS looks like this:

```
.field-validation-error
{
    background:url('/Styles/icons/validation-box-medium.gif') no-repeat;
    padding:10px 4px 4px 28px;
    width:188px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    clear:both;
    color:#780701;
}
```

[image: My background image - your welcome to use it]

And my view code looks like:

```
            <div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%: Html.LabelRequiredFor(model => model.Product.Price)%>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%: Html.TextBoxTwoDecimalFor(model => model.Product.Price)%>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Price)%>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have a CSS class for the "clear:both" i.e. I never us inline styles - but for the sake of the example I have omitted that.

You're welcome to use some or all of the contents of this post including the image :-)

Comment: Cheers matey, will give it a look when i get home, I assume you make sure all your validation messages adhere to the length provided in this example... I was thinking about having a split box which has the 2 ends and then an expandable centre for long validation messages... like the old html table design tricks... anyway thanks again!

Comment: You're correct - I thought the limited length would cause me grief but it's fine because it's inline. e.g. rather than saying "PRODUCT CODE cannot be empty." you can just say "Required field." because the error is pointing to the input field - it makes for much more generic/re-usable messages that fit neatly into complex forms.